# Using jQuery functions .each() and .live()

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery code for table calculations....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalregfee = 0;
    $('.reg_fee').each(function(){
        totalregfee+= parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $('.total_regfee').html(totalregfee);
});
```

It works perfect when the page loads, but if I go to the next page or increase the data rows on page using tablesorter.pager, total doesn't get updated. How can I use jQuery `.live()` on the above code?

Please ask if you need more details, thanks for support.

Comment: Put that code into a function and call it each time you want to update your total, whenever that is. Should work just fine.

Comment: Basically what @Jon said; `live()` is only going to work on an event; you haven't even defined what event to fire on yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a function

```
var updateTotal = function(){
    var totalregfee = 0;
    $('.reg_fee').each(function(){
        totalregfee+= parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $('.total_regfee').html(totalregfee);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //call it on document ready
    updateTotal();
    //call it when you click a button
    $('#button').click(updateTotal);


});
```

Then call it on document ready and whenever you need to uopdate the total

To use it with tablesorter you should bind it to sortend (this works when you sort the table)

```
$('#idOfYourTable').bind("sortEnd", updateTotal);
```

Comment: and then attach it to the pagination link using $.delegate

Comment: I think you'd better use live than delegate when you are using other plugins because delegate works only if the element you are delegating to is already present on the DOM while live automatically delegate to the window element

Comment: thanks for answer, i am using jquery.sorted.pager for table, but doesn't updated for next page.

Comment: Show us the full code so that we can help. Maybe post an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am using this [plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) for my tables and above code for data rows calculation.

Comment: i added an example to use it with sorting

Comment: how should i add yours given code in my table sorter code....

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tablesorter")
      .tablesorter({debug: false, widthFixed: true})
   .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
      .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#search"),
                          filterClearContainer: $("#search-clear"),
                          filterColumns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                          filterCaseSensitive: false});
});`